# PDO not calling the order of a row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have tried to make this work but it adds up all the rows not just 5 like I am trying to in the query

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("
select sum(correct) from exams where 
username = :username ORDER BY :testID DESC LIMIT :5");
```

Due to the problems with not being able to callthe last 5 rows I am unable to test the ordering string.

I have read questions similar to this on stackoverflow but still cant seem to get it right. maybe there are other problems with my code but I can always add that if requsted :)

the full code

```
   <?php

require('includes/config.php'); 

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); } 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$last5rate = $db->prepare("select sum(correct) from exams where username = :username ORDER BY :testID DESC LIMIT 5");
$last5rate->execute(array(':username' => $username));
for($i=0; $rows = $last5rate->fetch(); $i++){
    //Edit this row
$last5  = $rows['sum(correct)'];
$last5final = $last5 / 10;
 }
echo $last5final;

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are not binding limit then change your query

```
select sum(correct) from exams where username = :username ORDER BY :testID DESC LIMIT :5
$last5rate->execute(array(':username' => "$username"));

for($i=0; $rows = $last5rate->fetch(); $i++){
    $last5  = $rows['sum(correct)'];
 }
```

to

```
select sum(correct) as correct from exams where username = :username ORDER BY :testID DESC LIMIT 5
$last5rate->execute(array(':username' => $username,':testID' => $testID));
while ($row = $last5rate->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo $row['correct']; // or use it as you want
}
```

Comment: This is still giving me issues i have included all my code within the OP

Comment: When i use `:testID` i get a error " number of bound variables does not match number of tokens" but when i use just `testID` it sum all rows not just the 5 ihave updated my code in OP

Comment: You need to pass the value of 'testID', please look into the query again. if you don't have any value for order by than pass it hard coded so that it should not give you any error.

Comment: if you don't have value for `testID` then remove it from sql and from binding

Comment: if it's row id then change `ORDER BY :testID` to `ORDER BY testID` and `array(':username' => $username,':testID' => $testID)` to `array(':username' => $username)`

Comment: Thank you for your efforts :) testID is the row ID from my table

Comment: Thanks that is display fine :) the limit 5 is getting ignored, once again thank you for your answer

Comment: it should not ignore it but you can try limit with `0,5` as well

Comment: I have changed the title of this question to "PDO not calling the order of a row" ill ask a new question regarding the limit so delete the comments thats related to that :)